# Reverse number function not working properly after first run

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int rev(int i) {
    int ret;
    while (i >= 1) {
        ret += i%10;
        i /= 10;
        ret *= 10;
    }
    return ret/10;
}

int main() {

    //rev(4);
    cout << rev(123) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get "321", as I should.
But when I un-comment the line above it, I get "4321"!
Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial value of `int ret;` is undefined (any value). Replace it with `int ret = 0;`.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Uninitialized `ret`. You have a pre-existing garbage value getting mixed in with your computation.

Give

```
int ret = 0;
```

a go.